# Is it Possible to Update Dart Packages in Splash Screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a private dart package on Github. is it possible to find and update the latest version of the dart package when launching the app in Splash Screen.

Comment: whats the use case of this over engineering?

Comment: @Yadu my concern is to provide functional bug fixes update without letting users redownload the app. so I'm trying to separate my logical part from the app using packages. is there any possibility? please let me know.

Comment: that's a violation of rules set by playstore and appstore.

Answer (score 2):

Flutter needs all the information of your packages before compiling your app. The package information will be store at `pubspec.lock` file. The moment you build the app, Flutter will extract the package information from here. So the answer is it's not possible to check and update the package with Flutter codes after the app is built